# Ext.draw.Component gradient not displaying in IE

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I can't be the only person with this problem, but my searches have left me lost and confused.

I have a custom Ext.draw.Component that uses a gradient fill. My understanding is that older browsers don't support gradients, but I thought Sencha accounted for that with by adding CSS to the object rendered.

Component in **Chrome**:
[image: Chrome]
Component in **IE**:
[image: IE]

My questions are thus:

1. Can Ext.js render gradients to IE8 and IE9?  (IE10 displays fine)
2. Is there a way to determine if the browser is going to not render the gradient and I can just display something else (i.e. the compenent in IE wouldn't look so bad without the white elipses)?

**UPDATE**
Here is the code that generates the Stoplights. http://jsfiddle.net/wilsjd/Ts2qU/10/

```
    var sencha = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component', {
        width: 170,
        height: 170,
        renderTo: this.get('elementToRenderTo'),
        gradients: [{
            id: 'middleGradient',
            angle: 180,
            stops: {
                0: {
                    color: this.get('backgroundColor'),
                    opacity: 1
                },
                50: {
                    color: this.get('backgroundColor'),
                    opacity: .6
                },
                100: {
                    color: this.get('backgroundColor'),
                    opacity: 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            id: 'lightGradient1',
            angle: -90,
            stops: {
                0: {
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    opacity: 0.01
                },

                100: {
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    opacity: .8
                }

            }
        }, {
            type: 'radial',
            id: 'radialGradient1',
            centerX:123.88702,
            centerY:391.47498,
            radius:166.47372,
            focalX:124.57159,
            focalY:391.47498,
            stops: {
                0: {
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    opacity: 0.01
                },

                100: {
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    opacity: .8
                }

            }
        }],
        items: [{
            type: 'rect',
            x: 1.6620979,
            y: 52.362183,
            radius: 90,
            width: 448.10959,
            height: 1000,
            fill: 'url(#middleGradient)',
            stroke: 'none'
        }, {
            type: "circle",
            radius: 140,
            x:224,
            y:896,
            stroke: "#000000",
                'stroke-width': 7,
            fill: this.get('goodColor')
        }, {
            type: "circle",
            x:224,
            y:214,
            radius:140,
            stroke: "#000000",
                'stroke-width': 7,
            fill: this.get('poorColor')
        }, {
            type: "circle",
            x:224,
            y:555,
            radius: 140,
            stroke: "#000000",
                'stroke-width': 7,
            fill: this.get('cautionColor')
        }, {
            type: "ellipse",
            radiusX: 112,
            radiusY: 80,
            x: 224,
            y: 156,
            fill: 'url(#lightGradient1)'
        }, {
            type: "ellipse",
            radiusX: 112,
            radiusY: 80,
            x: 224,
            y: 498,
            fill: 'url(#lightGradient1)'
        }, {
            type: "ellipse",
            radiusX: 112,
            radiusY: 80,
            x: 224,
            y: 838,
            fill: 'url(#lightGradient1)'
        }, {
            type: "text",
            text: this.get('poorValue'),
            x: poorValueX,
            y: 210,
            fill: "Black",
            font: "80px bold"
        }, {
            type: "text",
            text: this.get('cautionValue'),
            x: cautionValueX,
            y: 550,
            fill: "Black",
            font: "80px bold"
        }, {
            type: "text",
            text: this.get('goodValue'),
            x: goodValueX,
            y: 890,
            fill: "Black",
            font: "80px bold"
        }, {
            type: "text",
            text: poorLabel,
            x: 500,
            y: 210 + poorChangeY,
            fill: "Black",
            font: "80px bold"
        }, {
            type: "text",
            text: cautionLabel,
            x: 500,
            y: 550 + cautionChangeY,
            fill: "Black",
            font: "80px bold"
        }, {
            type: "text",
            text: goodLabel,
            x: 500,
            y: 890 + goodChangeY,
            fill: "Black",
            font: "80px bold"
        }, {
            type: "text",
            text: this.get('title'),
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            fill: "Black",
            font: "100px bold"
        }, {
            type: "text",
            text: "Total = " + this.get('total'),
            x: 100,
            y: 1150,
            fill: "Black",
            font: "80px bold"
        }]
    });
```

Comment: IE8 uses VML, while IE9 & IE10 use SVG. They should render the same. VML also supports gradient so you might need to share some code. For your 2nd question, yes you can detect browser with ExtJS, you can also detect if your browser uses VML or SVG. Anyway you'll need to share some code on how you build your gradient.

Comment: I have actually figured out the second, I just add the ellipse if it is a "supported" browser, but I would still like there to be a way to have the same user experience cross-browser.

Comment: It is not the same, but there is an open bug "Internet Explorer 10 is incorrectly identified as not supporting CSS linear-gradients": http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265166-Bug-IE10-Linear-Gradients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ext.js can indeed render gradients in IE, but in this case it isn't working (still need source to determine why)
2. Added if statement to determine if the browser was IE8 or IE9 (I checked the document mode too - IE10 doesn't work if in IE8 document mode), and then add my ellipses)